# spring data jdbc use @query comments, How to match the parameters registered for entity

Tags: spring-el, spring-data-jdbc

```java
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update orders o set o.status =#{#order.status} ")
    Integer updateOrder(@Param("order") Order order);
    
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update orders o set o.status = #{#order.status}")
    Integer updateOrder(@Param("order") Order order);
```

I want to get the parameters of the order by means of order entity then update.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of SpEL support which wasn't implemented when the question was asked originally.

Support for it was added recently and will become available with 3.0.0-RC.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/619.